# The meaning of "the bitter one"

Tags: word-meaning

What does "the bitter one" mean in these lyrics?

> She's taking her time making up the reasons
> To justify all the hurt inside
>
> Guess she knows from the smile and the look in their eyes
> Everyone's got a theory about **the bitter one**
> They're saying, "Mamma never loved  her much"
> And, "Daddy never keeps in touch
>
> That's why she shies away from  human affection
> But somewhere in a private place
> She packs her bags for outer space
> And now she's waiting for the right kind of pilot to come.

from "To the Moon and back" by Savage Garden

Comment: Did you check the meaning of "bitter"? If that did not help, more detail is needed in your question.

Comment: @user3169 hi, yes of course I did but I thought it could have a lot of meanings.My guess is that it may be used to describe a anti-social someone  who struggles to adapt to the society.I do not have any further context but the lyrics in which I saw the term.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is more about lyric interpretation than English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that "she" (in the first sentence) is the "bitter one".  "bitter" in the sense of angry resentment of her past, which has made her bitter toward life (she can't taste any "sweetness" even in normally pleasant present experiences, because of her horrible past.)